# Matplotlib and Networkx - drawing multiple self loop

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to create a graph that may have multiple self loop. But, I am able to see only one self loop. So, is there any way to visualize it properly.

Here is my code.

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = nx.MultiDiGraph()
g.add_edge(0, 0)
g.add_edge(0, 1)
g.add_edge(1, 2)
g.add_edge(2, 2)
g.add_edge(2, 2)

count = g.number_of_edges(2, 2)
print(f'Edge count: {count}')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
nx.draw(g, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold', node_color='White', width=2)
plt.show()
```

Here is the output of the above code
[image]

Here edge count is showing two self loop but the visualization has some issue.

Comment: Pretty sure that networkx does not support visualisation of multi-edges, irrespective of whether they are a self-loop or not.